# Accordion with php form

Tags: php, jquery, html

Sorry now if this is a dumb question. But it's recking my head the past few days.

I'm making a webfront for a admin of a school that can easily input data into a database.
All my inputs are working. I just trying to make it easier for the user now.
So what my question is: Can I use an accordion / collapsible form using JQuery. Here what I've got at the moment

For explanation the code below is in the "form.php" file

```
    <?php

require_once 'inc/header.inc.php';
?>
    <form action=""  id="" method="POST">      
        <fieldset>

        <legend>Please Complete the Details</legend>
         <div class ="">
           <label for="FName" class="">Child's First Name</label>
           <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="FName" id="FName"  maxlength="9" class="form-control" required title="Please type the child's first name here">
           </div>
         </div>

        <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


        <legend>Please Complete the parent's details</legend>
         <div class ="">
           <label for="FName" class="">Parents First Name</label>
           <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="PFName" id="PFName"  maxlength="9" class="form-control" required title="Please type the parent's first name here">
           </div>
         </div>

        <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

        <legend>Please Complete the parent's details</legend>
        <div class ="">
           <label for="extraNo" class="">Extra Number, Optional</label>
           <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="extraNo" id="extraNo"  maxlength="15" class="form-control" required title="Please enter extra number here">
           </div>
         </div>
            <div class = "">
            <div class="input">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"value="Insert Record" name = "Submit">
         </div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>

    <?php
}
require_once 'inc/footer.inc.php';
?>
```

My styling and scripts are in my header.inc.php and footer.inc.php files.

What I'm looking to do is to have an accordion on each of the  tags so that when the user in navigating through the form it wont be just a big block of text.

So I'm just wondering. Do I put my code for the accordion into my header / footer files do to I put it into my form.php

Any replies or other suggestions would be great. P.S I'm not using Bootstrap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include jQuery UI ([Google Library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui)) and then set an id for your fieldset (for example, `accordian`).

Now you will need to use this jQuery:

```
$('#accordian').accordian({header:'legend'});
```

[Accordian API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

One final note, be sure to include BOTH jQuery AND jQuery UI in that order.  Generally, this is done in the header.php so that these resources are available to all pages.

Comment: Ok but for the "script src" do I put it into my "form.php" file or into my styling files ("header.php" and "footer.php") ?

Comment: @user3007858 It actually does not matter.  If you put it in your header, then it will be available to other pages that use that header.  If you put it in the form, it will be available to all pages that use the form.  I would avoid putting it in the footer, but that is really personal preference (kinda).

Comment: Doesn't seam to be working.
I've added


      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#accordion').accordion({header:'legend'});
  
  </script> 

to my header file and the <fieldset id="accordion"> to the "form.php"  Did I miss something?

Comment: @user3007858 Put the `.accordian()` inside of this: `$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});`.